# Browse to file removing link cell in SQL

Tags: mysql, vb.net

We have unique records created via a webpage and this has a browse for file to upload a image specific to this record. When the file is saved the URL location of the file is saved in SQL for that record to be recalled later in the system.

When you edit this record in the webpage and do not select a file, the SQL cell is made null.

here is the save code:

```
ByVal ID As HttpPostedFileBase
Dim folderPath As String = ""
                    If ID IsNot Nothing Then
                        folderPath = Server.MapPath("~/Content/ID/")
                        If Not Directory.Exists(folderPath) Then
                            Directory.CreateDirectory(folderPath)
                        End If

                        ID.SaveAs(folderPath & Record.UniqueID & ID.FileName)
                        Record.ID= "/Content/ID/" & Record.UniqueID & ID.FileName
                    End If
```

When the Browse for file is 'No File Chosen' it will overwrite the Record.ID making it null. do i need to add a text field to pull SQL URL through to stop the overwriting by checking if that is null?

Comment: Post the `ID` object's `SaveAs()` method.

Comment: Wouldnt that be:

 ID.SaveAs(folderPath & Record.UniqueID & ID.FileName)

Comment: No. That's when you call the method. Post the contents of the method.